# Destructor not called in uwp

Tags: c++, windows-10-universal

I have a simple c++ class - A which has some tasks in it.

```
concurrency::task<void> m_task1;
```

And I wanted to cancel the task in the destructor. But i can see the destructor is never executed. I am afraid this can create memory leak. Why the destructor is not executed?

```
class MyClass
    {
    public:
        explicit MyClass(MyException func);
        ~MyClass();
        void Start(int interval = 2000);
    private:
        concurrency::task<void> m_task;
        concurrency::cancellation_token_source m_cancellationToken;     
        ...
    };

/// <summary>Destructor.</summary>
MyClass::~MyClass()
{
  // I clean up here  
}
```

Comment: Unless you're writing .Net managed code, I'm assuming this should be tagged C++, not C++/CLI.

Comment: Is the destructor virtual?

Comment: @DavidYaw I am working on UWP c++ and my class is simple c++ class not a ref class. Please see my class in edit.

Comment: You destructor is not defined, it is only declared. Please post complete code which can be verified.

Comment: @Rishi it's the snippet from the header only. Of course it has some code in implementation.See the Edit

Comment: @sohel14_cse_ju, Please post [a verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @sohel14_cse_ju did you call delete manually to test whether the destructor works?  You can refer to the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/ref-classes-and-structs-c-cx#destructors).